# Storing the value in a variable and the value of the variable to an array gives different output

Tags: c

i am stuck with this problem.

```
int *foo(int *string,int len)
{
    int *newHex;
    int i=0,temp=0x00,l;
    int mask = 0xFF;
    printf("\nThe values of variable: ")
    for (i=0;i<len/2;i++)
    {
        //storing value in a variable
        l = ((string[i] & (mask>>i+1)) << i) | temp;                               
        temp = string[i] >> (7-i);
        printf("%d ",l);   //printing the variable
        newHex[i] = l;    //storing the value in an array
    }
    return (&newHex[0]);   //returning the base address of array
}

//in main
int *hex;
printf("\nThe values of array: ")
hex = foo(hex,len);
for (i=0;i<len/2;i++)
    printf(": %d ",hex[i]);
```

when i try to execute this chunk of code.

in function foo when i print the values of ' l ' variable i get the desired output.Then i copy the clues to array 'newHex'.
but while printing the values of the array in main. i get different output.
i am confused why this is happening. The both values should match right. What m i missing here.?

thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `len`, where is `main`? `hex` turned to `string` is also uninitialized.

Comment: You are not allocating memory for newHex.

Comment: isn't there a canonical duplicate for this kind of UB? should be closed with dupe & comment pointing out the error.

Comment: its just a part of code. no the whole code. do i need to post whole code for this problem?

Comment: questions should consist of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .. but you must allocate some memory for your pointers to point to using [`malloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and friends. Accessing them without doing so first invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no array at `newHex`, that's just an uninitialized pointer. This code has undefined behavior.

Comment: what should i do then?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are having different values is because you used your variable newHex wrong. When you declared a *newHex in your function, you didn't declare it as an array. You declared it as an regular integer. But then you assigned the value of l to newHex as if it is an array.So to fix your problem, change newHex where you declared to  an array. Do this in both your main function and in your function.

In main function:

```
int *hex[len/2];
```

In your function:

```
int *newHex[len/2];
```